# Javers - How to add extra commit metadata?

Tags: java, javers

Currently Javers records the username and the timestamp of the audit in the commit metadata but I would like to store the user id as well. Is it possible to add more fields to Javers commit metadata like user id or ip address?

Comment: Can't you just include that data in your domain model?

Comment: But that would mean I have to manually set and update the ip address every time a record changes. What I would like to do is add those data automatically just like how Javers currently records the username in the commit metadata

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `commit properties`. It's the Map of String properties that you can add to each commit and then use in queries. See example - https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#commit-property-filter

Comment: Is it possible to add those data automatically using `auto-audit` aspect? If so can you provide an example implementation?

Comment: https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#commit-properties-provider-bean

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you